# Ошибка в WidowsForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Я создавал приложение на С# и после добавления формы у меня появилась вот эта ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как её исправить?

Код формы, после которой появилась ошибка:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class AddRecepies : Form
    {
        public AddRecepies()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddProductTR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var label1 = new Label();

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = ProductTR.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Данная ошибка сообщает, что исполняемый код и код проекта отличаются. Исправить ошибку можно одним из решений:
Перестроив проект;
Перезапустив VS;
Перезагрузив ПК;

Comment: @Tivyram нет, в этом случае ошибка другая...

Comment: Такая штука бывает, если Вы что-то снесли в коде, относящиеся к элементам к графическим формы, минуя FormDesgner. Как правило, чаше всего это обработчики событий на клики элементов пользовательского интерфейса. Скорее всего у элемента AddProductTR на клике висит не AddProductTR_Click(), а что-то другое и возможно, что с другой сигнатурой.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибку исправил.